# WP7 XNA+Silverlight Templates missing

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, templates, xna

I got an issue with Visual Studio, Silverlight 5 Beta SDK and XNA.

I did a fresh install of all Visual Studio components I need to create the application I have in mind:

1. Visual C# 2010 Express
2. XNA Game Studio 4.0
3. Visual Web Developer 2010 Express
4. Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone
5. Visual Studio 2010 SP1
6. Silverlight 5 Beta Tools

However, when I start VS 2010 Express for Windows Phone and go to create a new project these are the templates I have:

[Missing Templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJLkY.png)

[image: Missing templates]

But there are a few templates missing.

How can I make appear the following templates:
[Full list of templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKucp.png)

[image]

So what am I missing in this? I believe I installed everything and still nothing appears.
Is it because I'm using the express edition of visual studio? it doesn't make much sense though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed that SDK correctly (uninstalled a previous installed SDK version correctly too)?

You could try and reset your vs2010 settings. This sometimes helps to restore missing project templates. You can do so like this:

- Go to Tools / Import Export Settings
- Choose to "Reset all Settings"
- Restart Visual Studio

No guarantees but that helped me once before, so it is probably worth a try.

Comment: I actually found the solution, but eventually forgot to post here about it.

I installed Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone 7 but I needed to install Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone 7.1, which is the version that comes with those templates.

Still, thanks a lot for answering ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just for others to know, you must have Visual Studio 2010 service pack 1([download link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691)) before that.