# Visual Studio 2010 lost the WP7 templates

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have a problem in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and WP7 SDK.

I have installed the WP7 SDK and when i tried to use Add an item... in my solution the list of installed templates was completely empty.

Then i updated to the WP7.5 SDK the same happened.

I uninstalled the SDK and reinstall nothing.

I tried to reset the settings using the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402493/wp7-xnasilverlight-templates-missing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780783/visual-studio-2010-missing-project-item-templates)

I uninstalled everything related to VS and reinstalled it with the same thing happened.

Any info to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you could try.

1. Make sure that the language of the IDE matches the one in your settings. Go to **Tools > Options > Environment > International Settings** and set the Language to **English**. Once done, go to **point 2**.
2. Most obvious - **devenv /installvstemplates**
3. Uninstall Visual Studio itself (not sure what you meant by *everything related*)
4. Open **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates** and **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates** - check that the templates are physically present in the folder.

Comment: I had tried all the above before posting the question.The problem didnt solved :(

Comment: Eventually i fixed it using a mix of the above but i dont remember  the sequence.I mark it as answered because no one else answered.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. The problem was in language settings: I used russian version of Windows 7, english version of VS2010 and installed russian version of WP7.1 SDK.

I fixed it with this:

> Tools > Options > Environment > International Settings and set the Language to "same as Windows language" (it means russian).